# Use ant xslt task using same input and output files

Tags: xslt, ant

It seems not possible to run the ant xslt task to do sorting on xml (for example) using the input file as output file w/o any temporary file.

I am using the following target to sort the content of all arxml files.

```
<target name="sort_arxml" depends="init" description="Do a XLST on all arxml files to sort their content">
    <tempfile property="sort.xslt" suffix=".xslt" deleteonexit="true" />
    <echo file="${sort.xslt}">
        <![CDATA[
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                        <xsl:sort select="child::*"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
        ]]></echo>
    <xslt style="${sort.xslt}" basedir="../Config" destdir="../Config" extension=".arxml" includes="**/*.arxml" excludes="**/AUTOSAR*"/>
</target>
```

But I cannot do this as it returns a an Exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: xxxx\Config\Developer\ComponentTypes\yyyy.arxml (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.transform(TraXLiaison.java:185)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.process(XSLTProcess.java:816)
```

If I use a different extension it works but then I have to copy the files back over the original ones.

**Does someone fixed this? and if, how?
Is it a matter of the transformer?**

System info:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Detected Java version: 1.7 in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
Detected OS: Windows 7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**XSLT itself cannot write to its input file, so there is nothing that the ant XSLT task can do to help you with your goal.**

By the way, there is nothing wrong with creating a temporary file or directory, and there are advantages to keeping XSLT input separate from the output.  The ant XSLT task can detect when it is necessary to re-run the transformation, and debugging is facilitated when input and output files are distinct.  You probably would be better off not trying to go against the grain.

**If you can't design around the need for the output files to be the same as the input files, just write to a separate output directory and replace the input directory with the output directory after the transformation:**

```
<target name="sort_arxml" depends="init" 
        description="Do a XLST on all arxml files to sort their content">

    <!-- [ same as in question ] -->

    <xslt style="${sort.xslt}" basedir="../Config" destdir="../ConfigTMP" 
          extension=".arxml" includes="**/*.arxml" excludes="**/AUTOSAR*"/>

    <delete dir="../Config"/>
    <move file="../ConfigTMP" tofile="../Config"/>

</target>
```

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer

Answer (score 0):

You can not read and write from/to the same file at the same time.

You have to choose another output filename (or different folder) and afterwards replace the old files by the new files.

The ant [Move Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) does overwrite the existing files by default.